# Database Abstraction Layer Check Table Failing

Tags: php, mysql, heidisql

I am having quite an issue regarding the check table query, but only via PDO.  Right now, I have a DBAL that has built in corruption fixing.  It uses MyISAM tables for primary storage purposes, and checks the table for corruption autonomously the first time it is accessed on a particular script.  If it's corrupt, it repairs the table, grabs all the ID's remaining, and compares these to the ID's in a backup table (SQLite for local deployments, InnoDB for server-side deployments) and pushes missing values back in.  This allows our developers to never have to worry about data corruption because the DBAL makes backups and repairs/restores autonomously.  The snag I have ran into is deployment.  For some reason:

```
    CHECK TABLE pointofcare.zentry_visit_answer MEDIUM
```

Returns "{msg_type=>status, msg_text=>ok}" as an array even though if I run that exact same query within heidisql, it returns as error rather than okay.  I am at my whits end trying to figure this one out.  The query failing all together would make sense, but returning one value in php and another in heidisql makes no sense.  The DB I am connecting to is on my local machine.  Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  There is a logic gate that determines the IP address (either 1ocal or WAN).  It was pointing to the DB on the WAN which doesn't contain corruption.  The local DB was the test case.  Whewww